# JWPlayer in Chrome plays mp4 video after 3 attempts to start

Tags: gwt, jwplayer, mp4

We use JWPlayer with GWT for play mp4 video file on web. The JWPlayer with three attempts to play an error. After the video plays without error. This error only into Google Chrome. 
Screenshots error and information about the video attached.
What could it be?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function configure(baseUrl, resourceId, isModal, type) {
        var isMobile = /android|ipad|iphone|ipod|blackberry|windows phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
        if (isMobile) {
            if (/android/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())){
                window.open(baseUrl + "?requestType=" + type + "&deviceType=2" + "&resId=" + resourceId,"_top");
            } else if (/ipad|iphone|ipod/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
                window.open(baseUrl + "?requestType=" + type + "&deviceType=3" + "&resId=" + resourceId,"_top");
            }
        } else {
            jwplayer("vpl"+ resourceId + "_"+ isModal).setup({
                flashplayer: 'medex/flash/jwplayer.flash.swf',
                file: baseUrl + "?requestType=" + type + "&deviceType=1" + "&resId=" + resourceId,          
                width: "100%",
                height: 681,
                type: "mp4",
                autostart: false,
                icons: false,
                shuffle: false,
                fullscreen: true,
                wmode: "transparent",
                bufferlength: 30,
                backgroundColor: "#000000"
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a code sample of your player setup?

Comment: Sample code added.

Comment: Sorry...still could be a number of different things. Do you have a link to the live player that you could paste?

Comment: This is personal room https://cabinet.med-exp.ru/MedexCliLogin.html. Login:TII0000000000003 Password:111    and this is smal instruction https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByWFTfiUDysWelZBMDY1Q1M2Tmc/view?usp=sharing Before running Сhrom, stop all processes it through the Windows Task Manager.

Comment: and video instruction https://youtu.be/ws0kp6SH2ec

Comment: Josie, do you have any information about of our problem?